# AWS SageMaker: GPU is not available for Notebook instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

I want to run my code in notebook instance on AWS Sagemaker.
My instance is ml.m5.4xlarge

But if I just import TensorFlow in standard way it, then TensorFlow on GPU is not available(only CPU is used):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

['']
```

What should I do in order to use GPUs for tensorflow?

P.S to be clear I don't need to deploy anything. I just want to train my model using notebook instance(for Kaggle competition)

**EDIT:** I have used conda_tensorflow2_p36 notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance ml.m5.4xlarge does not have any GPU. You have to choose an instance type with a GPU. Take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html)